# When my android App get firebase message notification, then shutting down

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I practice FCM send and get notification.
It works at test package, but not works at my own package..

Here is my log..

2020-07-23 15:11:29.433 19947-19947/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=lg.uplusbox cmp=lg.uplusbox/.controller.fcm.FcmInstanceIdService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{91a4603 u0a198 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 proclist:19947, seq(0,0,0)}
2020-07-23 15:11:29.437 19947-19947/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11400
2020-07-23 15:11:29.437 19947-19947/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-07-23 15:11:29.444 19947-19947/? V/FA: Collection enabled
2020-07-23 15:11:29.445 19947-19947/? V/FA: App package, google app id: lg.uplusbox, 1:814604498086:android:0700c6cb9bf60793
2020-07-23 15:11:29.445 19947-19947/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app lg.uplusbox
2020-07-23 15:11:29.445 19947-19947/? D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-07-23 15:11:29.446 19947-19947/? V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: -1683691085
2020-07-23 15:11:29.450 19947-19947/? V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2020-07-23 15:11:29.467 19947-19970/? V/FA: Using measurement service
2020-07-23 15:11:29.467 19947-19970/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-07-23 15:11:29.486 19947-19970/? V/FA: Using measurement service
2020-07-23 15:11:29.486 19947-19970/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-07-23 15:11:29.588 19947-19970/? D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-07-23 15:11:29.588 19947-19970/? V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
2020-07-23 15:11:34.642 19947-19970/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Comment: my own app shutting down when get push message..

Comment: Hi @cm94 welcome to SO.  I see you have added your code as answers by mistake.  You should add those to your question by clicking the above "edit" link.  You should also delete the below answers.

Comment: Try following this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/70858784/13546426

Answer (score 0):

2. TestActivity

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView textView;
TextView textView2;
String newToken;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Log.d("FMS_MAIN", "onCreate() called");

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
            newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();

            println("token: " + newToken);// it work..
            Log.d("Mytoken", "token : " + newToken); // not work..

        }
    });
    Log.d("Mytoken", "token : " + newToken);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String instancedId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId();                 println("instanced id: " + instancedId); // it work..!
            Log.d("Mytoken", "instance id: " + instancedId);// but it not work..
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this,instancedId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // it not work too..
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    println("onNewIntent() called");
    Log.d("FMS_MAIN", "onNewIntent() called");

    if (intent != null) {
        println("Intent is Not null");
        processIntent(intent);
    } else {
        println("Intent is null");
    }

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}

private void processIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("FMS_MAIN", "processIntent called");
    int ekey = intent.getIntExtra("ekey", 2);
    String ename = intent.getStringExtra("ename");

    println("ekey: " + ekey);
    textView.setText("");
    textView.setText("[" + ename + "]'s eKey : " + ekey);
}

public void println(String data) {
    textView2.setText(data + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

3. MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    private static final String TAG = "FMS";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e(TAG,"onNewToken() called: "+s);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG,"onMessageReceived() called");

        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
        String ekey = remoteMessage.getData().get("ekey");
        String ename = remoteMessage.getData().get("ename");

        if (title != null && body != null && ekey != null && ename != null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Title: "+title+", body: "+body+", ekey: "+ekey);

            sendNotification(title,body);
            newActivityIntent(ekey,ename);
        }
    }

    private void newActivityIntent(String key,String name){
        Log.d(TAG, "sendToActivity() called. ekey: " +key);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("ekey",Integer.valueOf(key));
        intent.putExtra("ename",name);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void sendNotification(String title, String text) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "sendNotification() called");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is PushSendProject

```
public void sendEmergancyData() {
        Log.d("PUSH","Start");
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
            JSONObject pushData = new JSONObject();

            pushData.put("ekey", elderlyData.getEkey());
            pushData.put("ename", name);
            pushData.put("homeIot", homeIot);

            pushData.put("title", name);
            pushData.put("body", "emergancy");

            JSONObject push = new JSONObject();
            push.put("to", regid);
            push.put("data", pushData);

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, push, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("Emergancy_Push","success:"+response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Emergancy_Push","error:"+error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("Authorization", Constants.FCM_API_KEY);
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            queue.add(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("PUSH","End");
    }
```

I already know Receive App's token before, so it used regid in Send App.