# Insert data to Realtime Database does not works

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to create an app if someone want to use my app they must create a user.
When they register they will insert first name, last name, phone and email address.
After I confirm that the phone is theirs by using Firebase authorization I want to insert his data to a table named Users in my RealTime Database.

When I tried to do it by using this function:

**EDIT: I added the onComplete function but it doesn't execute **

```
private void storeNewUserData() {
        FirebaseDatabase rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = rootNode.getReference("Users");
        User user = new User(phone,firstName,lastName,email);
        reference.setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(this);
    }


@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
    if(task.isSuccessful()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inserted User: "+phone+firstName+lastName+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The database has not been updated but the Toast appeared (with all the data).

I don't think there is a problem in my code maybe it's a problem in my Firebase account.. Anyway I add the rules to this database and an image of the table.

**Rules**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
        ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

[image]

**build.gradle(app)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

}
```

';

```
private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            User user = new User(phone,firstName,lastName,email);
            storeNewUserData();
            Toast.makeText(PhoneAuthActivity.this, "Logged in as "+phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(PhoneAuthActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }


    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(PhoneAuthActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**logcat**

```
2021-03-30 03:41:02.326 15207-15345/com.example.teorialearning E/FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
2021-03-30 03:41:02.344 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 396
2021-03-30 03:41:02.345 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Activity paused, time: 15824705
2021-03-30 03:41:02.389 15207-15207/com.example.teorialearning E/zzf: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification
2021-03-30 03:41:02.391 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 15824751
2021-03-30 03:41:02.395 15207-15245/com.example.teorialearning W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2021-03-30 03:41:02.641 15207-15207/com.example.teorialearning D/MAIN_TAG: onCodeSent:ALiwoWIdFZrl9ResXiUM94aPJW-csmRjdDOqoa9DTOkNQbv2Vf8YN7X6mvBwXgg9MJxEnFUVoE2rWAP2JzpT8QdBcRK2kIi82e_uO3pXW_rC5CZqWgJaqYqPO6nMOxiavmaJELnkSRtTXo6HoYoEY2_CmtVplEbz2Q
2021-03-30 03:41:02.644 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:02.677 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:02.739 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:04.679 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:04.789 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:07.416 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2021-03-30 03:41:08.627 15207-15245/com.example.teorialearning W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2021-03-30 03:41:08.668 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:08.685 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:08.691 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:08.696 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:08.755 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:08.936 15207-15245/com.example.teorialearning W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2021-03-30 03:41:09.147 15207-15245/com.example.teorialearning D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( QgYB9guxYgT2AQbr8u9CVrGnELw2 ).
2021-03-30 03:41:09.149 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:09.178 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 6787
2021-03-30 03:41:09.180 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2021-03-30 03:41:09.181 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Activity paused, time: 15831539
2021-03-30 03:41:09.189 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:09.193 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2021-03-30 03:41:09.212 15207-15225/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: onActivityCreated
2021-03-30 03:41:09.229 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 15831590
2021-03-30 03:41:09.233 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:09.243 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2021-03-30 03:41:09.244 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2021-03-30 03:41:09.295 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning D/FA: Connected to remote service
2021-03-30 03:41:09.296 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2021-03-30 03:41:09.298 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:09.329 15207-15207/com.example.teorialearning W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
2021-03-30 03:41:09.330 15207-15207/com.example.teorialearning W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
2021-03-30 03:41:11.206 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:13.170 15207-15333/com.example.teorialearning D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4856c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae483990)
2021-03-30 03:41:14.310 15207-15257/com.example.teorialearning V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2021-03-30 03:42:02.393 15207-15348/com.example.teorialearning W/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] Timed out waiting for SMS.
```

P.S: I'm using Android studio

Comment: You should use a `ValueEventListener` to track changes in a specific node/branch.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a complete listener to the setValue() method?  Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I haven't tried please attach code so I can try it

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Please attach code so I can try it

Comment: reference.setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);

Comment: @AlexMamo the task is not successfully completed how can I know why?

Comment: Try to log the message that comes when the task is not successful, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo I just find out that onComplete doesn't execute...

Comment: Which Toast message is displayed? Are you also sure you have an internet connection on the device/emulator?

Comment: @AlexMamo I used this in my manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

I get no Toast onComplete doesn't execute

Comment: Most likely, you don't have an internet connection on the device/emulator, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo I does get the Toast in onSuccess (after storeNewUserData())

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm not sure...

Comment: @AlexMamo but I'm pretty sure... I added the permission

Comment: Internet permissions are not necessary when writing data in Firebase. So most likely you don't have an internet connection (**not** internet permission) on the device.

Comment: @AlexMamo should I use my physical android device?

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried using my physical device  but still no change..

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal help

Comment: @AlexMamo help,

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by changing my device's internet connection network. The app won't work on mobile data, but it worked on the WIFI of some other device.

> The reason behind the problem isn't clear yet.

Reference answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/51122769/13546426